# magento add session messages to cms page

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

In my Magento site I have a custom signup form and a CMS thank-you page that the user is redirected to after they complete the form.  Is there a way to include the session messages in the CMS page?

I've tried playing w/ the **Layout Update XML** field, but I'm not getting anywhere

Here is what I've tried so far, all w/ no luck.

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="gloabl_messages" />
<block type="core/messages"  name="messages" as="global_messages" />

{{block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="gloabl_messages" }}
{{block type="core/messages"  name="messages" as="global_messages" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

That should display any messages in the core/session class.  Make sure the messages are being set on the core session.  It is possible they are being set on the customer session.  Mage::getSingleton('core/session') gets the core session.  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') gets the customer session, etc.